# Quotient ring and Boolean algebra correspondence

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, boolean-algebra

While reading a probability paper titled [Gröbner bases and factorisation in discrete probability and Bayes](https://doi.org/10.1023/A:1026505815343),  I came across the explanation:

The set of indicator functions $I_i$ form a Boolean algebra that is in one-to-one correspondence with the quotient of the ring $\mathbb{R}[x_1, \ldots, x_n]$ with respect to the relationships $x_i(x_i - 1)=0$ where $x_i$ represents $I_i$.

$I_i$ is defined to be the indicator function $I_i(\omega) = 1 \;\textrm{if}\;  \omega \in A_i \;\textrm{else}\; 0$, $i = 1, \ldots, n$.

I have a rudimentary understanding of rings, but can you please explain the correspondence shown here?

Cheers

**Edit**: In the rest of the paper, the authors don't seem to limit themselves to $\mathbb{F}_2$. In fact, I can't see a need for the use of the minus sign in $x_i(x_i-1)$ if the field is $\mathbb{F}_2$. I can't verify if the coefficients of the polynomials are disregarded yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A nice exposition of Stone's cryptomorphism between Boolean algebras and Boolean rings is in Burris and Sankappanavar's textbook [A Course in Universal Algebra](http://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/~snburris/htdocs/UALG/univ-algebra.pdf#page=154). There you'll also find a presentation of Boolean products - a powerful tool that facilitates the transfer of Boolean algebra results to other algebraic structures - leading to very general representation theories.

Answer (score 3):

I assume $i$ is an element of $\{ 1, 2, ... n \}$.  The correspondence comes from identifying $x_i$ with the indicator function of $\{ i \}$.

But the sentence you quote is imprecise.  If you wanted a Boolean algebra (more precisely, a Boolean ring), you would take the base field to be $\mathbb{F}_2$, not $\mathbb{R}$.  If you wanted real multiples of indicator functions, you wouldn't say "the set of indicator functions."